# Proving a sequence of function is point wise convergent to 1/x

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Hw Exercise: Let $f_n(x) = \min \left( \dfrac{1}{x}, n \right) $.
> Prove using the definition of point wise convergence that $f_n \to
>  \dfrac{1}{x} $ on $(0,1)$ and explain why $f_n(x)$ is bounded but
> $f(x)$ is unbounded.

### my answer:

Let $x \in (0,1)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We must find some $N$ so that if $n> N$ then $|f_n(x) - 1/x | < \epsilon$.

We observe that if we choose $N=1$ then any $n>1$ will have $f_n-1/x = 0 $ and so that $|f_n(x) - 1/x| < \epsilon $ is satisfied trivially.

Am I overcomplicating this. Is this proof rigorous enough?

As for boundedness, This is easy since $|f_n(x)| \leq n$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and if we had and $M$ so that $1/x < M$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, then we have a contradiction by choosing $x = 1/M$: $M<M$ therefore, there is no $M$ so that $1/x < M$ meaning $1/x$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that if $n>1$, then $f_n(x)-\frac1x=0$. That is wrong: $f_2\left(\frac13\right)=2\neq3=\frac1{1/3}$.

Take $x\in(0,1)$ and take $\varepsilon>0$. Now, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<x$. Then, if $n\geqslant N$, $f_n(x)=\frac1x$ and therefore $\left|f_n(x)-\frac1x\right|=0<\varepsilon$.

What you wrote about boundness is correct.

Comment: Can $N$ depende on $x$? I was thinking on choosing $N = floor(1/x)$ but I guess I am messing up the quantifiers

Comment: *Of course* that $N$ can depend on $x$. We are talking about *poinwise* convergence, right? It's when we're talking about *uniform* convergence that we're after a $\varepsilon$ which does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I see now. So a choice of $N = \floor(x)$ would work as well no?

Comment: No; if $x\in(0,1)$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$. Take $\left\lceil\frac1x\right\rceil$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that for e.g. $x=0.01\in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon=0.5>0$, it suffice to pick $N=1$ to achieve $|f_n(x)-\frac1x|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. So in particular, this should hold for $n=42$. But
$$\left|f_{42}(0.01)-\frac1{0.01}\right|=\left|\min\left\{\frac1{0.01},42\right\}-\frac1{0.01}\right| =\left|42-100\right|=58>0.5$$

Think again - perhaps sketch the first few $f_n$.